# Connected subsets problem

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Is it True or False: If $A$ and $C$ are connected subsets of the metric space $X$, and if $A \subset B \subset C$ then $B$ is connected. If true, prove it's true. If false, give a counter-example to prove it's false

My work: I think it's true, right?

edit: false

Comment: What does A c B c C mean?

Comment: @mixedmath, inclusions as subspaces, I believe.

Comment: If Sigur is right, then this is false.

Comment: Take $A$ one branch of an hyperbole. Take $B$ the hyperbole. Take $C$ the plane.

Comment: Your work is *to think it is true* ?

Comment: my counterexample says false

Comment: well, the other says false too. at first i thought its true but i followed the an example i did and found its false

Comment: $A=D(0,1)=\{x\in \Bbb R^n \ / \ \|x\|\leq 1\}$ , $B=A\cup (6,0,\ldots,0)$ and $C=\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @chris, you should read more good books on the subject before to ask here. Reading is fundamental to learn topology or analysis.

Comment: we dont have a book for our class, i know it sounds funny but my professor uses his brain to lecture us. So im using the book i rent from the library

Comment: Does anyone have one or two examples to show? I'd like to post a picture of my work but i cant upload it due to "lack" of steps

Answer (score 0):

Let $A:=\{0\}$, $B:=\{0,1\}$ and $C:=[0,1]$ in $\Bbb R$.